# Mini DisplayPort to USB 3.0? Is it possible?

Tags: usb, displayport, adapter, mini-displayport

I think not.

But maybe yes...

Is it possible to make USB port from mini displayport in laptop by adapter or something?

I know it is possible in reverse, but is it possible this way?

I have mini displayport in my laptop and if possible would gladly have another one USB port :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. DisplayPort isn't a multi-purpose port.

> I know it is possible in reverse

Actually, not really. USB 3.0 isn't DisplayPort-compatible, but you can use it to connect a DisplayPort-capable graphics adapter. USB type C connector supports video signal, but it's a connector feature, not USB feature.